# Second line is shifted by two tabs in XSLT while converting XML into Text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below xml and I wrote an XSLT to get output into Text format, but second line on wards, the output is shifted by two tabs and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

Is anything wrong with the xslt? What's that makes the second line shifted?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <businessobjects>
        <entry>
            <HeaderLine>
                <HeaderRow>H</HeaderRow>
                <HeaderBusinessUnit/>
                <CurrentTime>0704202004:47:43</CurrentTime>
                <TotalAmountCredit>-6.084732570000003E6</TotalAmountCredit>
                <TotalAmountDebit>6.194972230000004E6</TotalAmountDebit>
                <LineEntries>948</LineEntries>
            </HeaderLine>
            <LineDetails>
                <Line>L</Line>
                <HeaderBusinessUnit/>
                <FinancialYear>2020</FinancialYear>
                <Period>5</Period>
                <EndDate>20200101</EndDate>
                <Period>5</Period>
                <GLBusinessUnit>UTEP1</GLBusinessUnit>
                <GLAccount/>
                <EntryType>DEBITJOURNALENTRY</EntryType>
                <Amount>10000</Amount>
                <Currency>USD</Currency>
                <CostCenter>14026800</CostCenter>
                <ContractCode>L0498</ContractCode>
                <ContractName>Base Case - AC</ContractName>
                <ContractLineCode>1886</ContractLineCode>
                <PostingCode>1</PostingCode>
            </LineDetails>
            
            
        </entry>
    </businessobjects>
</document>
```

## XSLT Used

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name='newline'>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="businessobjects">
       <xsl:for-each select="entry">
           <xsl:for-each select="HeaderLine">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(HeaderRow,'|',HeaderBusinessUnit,'|',
                CurrentTime,'|',TotalAmountCredit,'|',
                TotalAmountDebit,'|',LineEntries,$newline)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:for-each select="LineDetails">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(Line,'|',HeaderBusinessUnit,'|',FinancialYear,
                   '|',Period,'|',EndDate,'|',GLBusinessUnit,'|',GLAccount,'|',EntryType,'|',Amount,'|',Currency,'|',CostCenter,'|',ContractCode,'|',ContractName,'|',ContractLineCode,'|',PostingCode,$newline)"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Output

```
H||0704202004:47:43|-6.084732570000003E6|6.194972230000004E6|948
        L||2020|5|20200101|UTEP1||DEBITJOURNALENTRY|10000|USD|14026800|L0498|Base Case - AC|1886|1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but second line on wards, the output is shifted by two tabs and I'm
> not sure why.

Because your `$newline` variable contains a line break and two tabs:

```
<xsl:variable name='newline'>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Either change it to:

```
    <xsl:variable name='newline'>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
```

or (preferably, IMHO) get rid of the variable and use the exact line break character/s you want instead, e.g.

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put all that into the variable

```
<xsl:variable name='newline'>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

I would rather use `<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>`. If you want to spell it out with `xsl:text` as you have tried then you will have to insert just the line break with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="newline">
  <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```